# What is the difference between page layout and lightning page layout?

Tags: page-layout

What is the difference between page layout and lightning page layout?
When should I create a new page layout versus lightning page layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lightning page layouts are specific to Lightning Experience, while standard page layouts are more "classic" oriented, however, will display in LEX.

You will find that Lightning page layouts do not support the same elements as the ones in classic page layouts, for example:

> - Expanded lookups
> - Mobile cards
> - S-controls
> - Tags

Obviously, if your users have already adopted LEX, you will want to use the Lightning page layouts or use the Lightning app builder. However, the lightning app builder(s) pages can only be used in a Salesforce app or in Lightning Experience.

You will also notice that the lightning app builder will give you more flexibility on customizing your layout since you can easily point, click, drag and drop elements in the interface since it is component based.

Page Layout in classic:
[image]

Page layout in LEX:
[image]

Lightning App Builder:
[image]
[image]

Documentation:

[Page Layouts in Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=layouts_in_lex.htm&type=0)

[Lightning App Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_app_builder_overview.htm&type=5)