# Account Related List not visible on Account Lightning Page

Tags: lightning

I am trying to view the Account Related List on Account Lightning Page and have made the parent Account Field as visible for all the profiles available in my org.
I am still not able to view the Related list in lightning. (users with System Admin Profile are able to see it in LEX and other users can see it in classic but not in LEX) Also the lightning page is the App default so i am sure it it referencing the correct page.
Can anyone please point out what i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you could check:-

1. Are there any component visibility have been set? check for Related List standard component by clicking on setup--> Edit page --> click on related list component on canvas of lightning app builder--> check in right bottom of the screen for component visibility filter
2. Is your admin has put the related list component on the page or not?

Note:- Page layout in classic and Lightning comes from different place. You can refer this question:- [What is the difference between page layout and lightning page layout?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/197750/what-is-the-difference-between-page-layout-and-lightning-page-layout)

Comment: Found the solution, I had vlocity installed in my org, and had to give access to a vlocity field called Root Account because of which the Account related list was not showing up. As Parent Account field is of type Hierarchical, it is some how also referencing the vlocity field to display the accounts.